# No se ejecuta mi segundo método de jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un método que regresa el id de un dropdownlist, este metodo lo utilizo ya que tengo un foreach que me regresa los datos de un modelo y se repite el id se ellos asi que con esto traigo el id cada que selecciono uno de ellos.

Solo obtengo el id en el que va, para despues concatenar esto en una variable y despues el resultado colocarlo en otro metodo de jquery, pero no me lo ejecuta.

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Muchas gracias.

```javascript
    $('body').on('change', '#items select', function () {
      let id = $(this).attr('id'),
      /*id2 = id.split(' '),*/
      id2 = id.slice(-1)
      id3 = id2;
      id4 = id;
    });

    var id3;
    var id4;
    var con = '#IDCATTIPOCAPACITACION1' + id3;

    $(con).change(function () {
      var url = '/' + "Capacitacion/GetFinalidadList";
      var ddlsource = "#IDCATTIPOCAPACITACION";
      $.getJSON(url, { IDCATTIPOCAPACITACION: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
        var items = '';
        
        $("#IDCATFINALIDAD").empty();
        
        $.each(data, function (i, finalidad) {
          items += "<option value='" + finalidad.value + "'>" + finalidad.text + "</option>";
        });
        
        $('#IDCATFINALIDAD' + id3).html(items);
      });    
    });
```

Comment: Hola miguel creo que el código tiene errores de estructura

Comment: Por favor indica qué error estas obteniendo